# std::unordered_map pass by reference

Tags: c++

I usually code in C. Now moving to C++. I have a `std::unordered_map` with 60 million entries. It is loaded once only and would not be modified later. I would like to pass it to some functions from time to time. But this code would copy the hash map every time:

```
typedef unordered_map<uint64_t, mer*> mer_map;
void test_pass_by_ref3(mer_map kmers) {
}

void test_pass_by_ref2(mer_map kmers) {
    test_pass_by_ref3(kmers);
}

void test_pass_by_ref(mer_map kmers) {
    test_pass_by_ref2(kmers);
}
```

If I want to pass the `pointer` only, how to pass it and query it as usual: `value = mer_map[key]`? I searched and find the `passing by reference` syntax:

```
void foo(const ClassName &name)
{
    ClassName& temp = const_cast<ClassName&>(name);
    ... ....
}
```

But it seems cannot compiled. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Using a reference would be a good C++ approach.  Show the error you're getting.

Comment: Why not just pass a non-const reference?

Comment: Yes, I tried the not-const method suggested by @juanchopanza as well, it also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am guessing your problem is that `operator[]` is non `const`, because it adds a default constructed element when accessed with a key that isn't already in the map.
You can use `at()`, which assumes the key is present and throws an exception otherwise:

```
typedef unordered_map<uint64_t, mer*> mer_map;

void foo(const mer_map& m)
{
  mer* val = m.at(key);
}
```

or use `std::unordered_map::find()`:

```
void foo(const mer_map& m)
{
  auto it = m.find(key);
  if (it != m.end())
  {
    // element is in map, use it
    mer* val = it->second;
  }
}
```

**Note**: You *could* also bypass the problem by passing a non-const reference, but by doing so you are saying the function would modify the map. You should only use a non-const reference if you really intend to modify an object.

```
void foo(mer_map& m)
{
  mer* val = m[key];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use pass by reference your functions should be declared like

```
typedef unordered_map<uint64_t, mer*> mer_map;
void test_pass_by_ref3(mer_map& kmers) {
}

void test_pass_by_ref2(mer_map& kmers) {
    test_pass_by_ref3(kmers);
}

void test_pass_by_ref(mer_map& kmers) {
    test_pass_by_ref2(kmers);
}
```

This will work normal for the access operator

```
mer_map[key]
```

and to access member functions something like

```
mer_map.find(
```

---

To pass a pointer they should be of the form

```
typedef unordered_map<uint64_t, mer*> mer_map;
void test_pass_by_poi3(mer_map *kmers) {
}

void test_pass_by_ref2(mer_map *kmers) {
    test_pass_by_poi3(kmers);
}

void test_pass_by_ref(mer_map *kmers) {
    test_pass_by_poi2(kmers);
}
```

However in the pointer version to use the access operator you have to dereference the pointer first.

```
(*mer_map)[key]
```

and to access member functions something like

```
kmers->find(
```

Answer (score 0):

For `map` and `unordered_map` the index operator `[]` is non-const because calling it with an index that doesn't exist will cause that element to be created.  You use `at()` if you don't want to create the element.  Then you can use const reference to `map` or `unordered_map`.  Be aware that `at()` will throw if the element does not exist.

You can use an iterator to test for existence:

```
bool
esists(const mer_map& kmers, uint64_t i)
{
  unordered_map<uint64_t, mer*::const_iterator it = kmers.find(i);
  return it != kmers.end();
}
```

Or you could just access mer_maps through iterators in your code.